# Some child elements do not affect the parent's height

Tags: html, css

I am building a design for my university but have come across this peculiar problem: the `<div>` element' height is not affected by its insides.

Just take a look at these screenshots:

[image: the outer <code><div></code>]

[image: the inner <code><label></code>]

[image: the inner <code><textarea></code>]

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shybovycha/dV6Xj/)

*Just to make some sense:* I'm trying to build something complicated (for me) without using tables (only CSS - we are living in a modern web-epoch though =) ). Here's my goal:

[image: what i am trying to implement]

I have some long and messy HTML and CSS code - I'm truly not a designer yet. Here it is:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>verstka</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="verstka.css" media="all" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="header angled-stripes">
                <div class="logo"></div>

                <div class="right-menu">
                    <div class="quick-links links">
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="/">Home</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="/">Login</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <span>Sitemap</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="quick-search">
                        <form action="" method="get" onsubmit="javascript:void(0);">
                            <input type="text" name="q" size="20" />
                            <a href="/" onclick="return false;" class="button">search</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="top-menu">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="/" class="products">Products</a>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <a href="/" class="download">Download</a>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <a href="/" class="support">Support</a>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <a href="/" class="contacts">Contacts</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="middle table-positioning">
            <div class="row-positioning">
                <div class="left-column">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="block product angled-stripes">
                            <div class="title">BASIC Package</div>

                            <div class="body">
                                <img src="product-green.png" />

                                <span>blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah</span>

                                <div class="links">
                                    <a href="/" class="item">Details</a>
                                    <a href="/" class="item">Download</a>
                                </div>

                                <a href="/" class="button">purchase now</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clearer"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block product angled-stripes">
                            <div class="title">FULL Package</div>

                            <div class="body">
                                <span>lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</span>
                                <div class="links">
                                    <a href="/" class="item">Details</a>
                                    <a href="/" class="item">Download</a>
                                </div>

                                <a href="/" class="button">purchase now</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clearer"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="block plain">
                            <div class="title">Popular Products</div>

                            <ul class="green-arrow-markered">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/">Set True Image 9.0</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="/">Standard Recorder 6.5</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="/">Disk Director Upgrade 4.56</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="/">ZippeNotes 6.22</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="footer">
                        &copy;<span class="bolder">Software Company</span>

                        <div class="links">
                            <a href="/" class="item">Privacy Policy</a>
                            <a href="/" class="item">Terms of Use</a>
                            <div class="clearer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="right-column">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="post">
                            <div class="title green-title">Company Address</div>
                            <div class="image"><img src="company-photo.jpg" alt="company photo"></div>
                            <div class="content"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post left-post">
                            <div class="title">Contact Form</div>

                            <form action="#" onsubmit="javascript:void(0);">
                                <div class="input">
                                    <label for="name">Your full name:</label>
                                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="input">
                                    <label for="email">E-mail address:</label>
                                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="input">
                                    <label for="phone">Your phone:</label>
                                    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="input">
                                    <label for="message">Your message</label>
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <input type="submit" />
                            </form>

                            <div class="row">
                                <a href="#" class="button">reset</a>
                                <a href="#" class="button">submit</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="highlighted-block post">

                            <div class="title green-title">
                                <img src="newsletter" alt="newsletter icon" />

                                <div>
                                    <span class="uppercase">newsletter</span><br /><span class="sub-title">signup</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clearer"></div>

                            <form action="#" onsubmit="javascript:void(0);">
                                <label for="newsletter-name">Enter your name, please:</label>
                                <input id="newsletter-name" name="name" type="text" />

                                <label for="newsletter-email">Enter your e-mail, please:</label>
                                <input id="newsletter-email" name="email" type="text" />

                                <a href="#" class="button">subscribe now</a>
                            </form>

                            <div>
                                <strong>Note:</strong>
                                <span>lorem ipsum ololo!</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearer"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="footer">
                        <div class="links">
                            <a href="#" class="item">Home</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">Products</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">Download</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">Support</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">Contacts</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">Login</a>
                            <a href="#" class="item">Sitemap</a>
                            <div class="clearer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0 0 80px 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #313131;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

a, a:hover, a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}

/*.links .item:nth-child(n+2):before {
    content: '|';
}
*/

.links .item:nth-child(n+2) {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
}

.links .item {
    color: #9c9c9c;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.links a.item:visited {
    color: #9c9c9c;
}

.links a.item:hover {
    color: #9c9c9c;
}

.bolder {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.footer {
    color: #9c9c9c;
}

.middle .left-column .content .block.product:nth-child(n+1) {
    /*background: #8dc63f;*/
    background-color: #86bc3c;
    /*background-size: 25px 25px;*/
    /*box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #77ad32;*/
}

.middle .left-column .content .block.product:nth-child(n+2) {
    /*background: #ee8911;*/
    background-color: #ee8911;
    /*background-size: 25px 25px;*/
    /*box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #eb7e0e;*/
}

.middle .left-column .content .block.product .title {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-shadow: 2px -1px 1px black;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.middle .left-column .content .block.product:nth-child(n+1) .title {
    background: #6ce25d; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6ce25d 16%, #4ebb30 36%, #bee884 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(16%,#6ce25d), color-stop(36%,#4ebb30), color-stop(100%,#bee884)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6ce25d 16%,#4ebb30 36%,#bee884 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6ce25d 16%,#4ebb30 36%,#bee884 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6ce25d 16%,#4ebb30 36%,#bee884 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6ce25d 16%,#4ebb30 36%,#bee884 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6ce25d', endColorstr='#bee884',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

.middle .left-column .content .block.product:nth-child(n+2) .title {
    background: #db8a08; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #db8a08 17%, #c76307 36%, #ef9366 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(17%,#db8a08), color-stop(36%,#c76307), color-stop(100%,#ef9366)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #db8a08 17%,#c76307 36%,#ef9366 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #db8a08 17%,#c76307 36%,#ef9366 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #db8a08 17%,#c76307 36%,#ef9366 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #db8a08 17%,#c76307 36%,#ef9366 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#db8a08', endColorstr='#ef9366',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

.middle .left-column .content .block .body .links .item:nth-child(n+2) {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.middle .left-column .content .block .body .links .item {
    color: #fff;
}

.middle .left-column .content .block.product .body img {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.middle .left-column {
    width: 20%;
    max-height: 350px;
}

.middle .right-column {
    width: 65%;
}

.middle .right-column .content {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #1c1c1c;
}

.top .header .quick-links .item {
    color: #fff;
}

.top .header {
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.top .header .right-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}

.top .header .right-menu .quick-links {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.top .header .right-menu .quick-search {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 10px;
}

.top .header .right-menu .quick-search form {
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.top .header .right-menu .quick-search form * {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.button {
    color: #fff !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #a4dff2;
    border: 1px solid #027499;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: #17688d;
    font-size: 10pt !important;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 70px;
    max-height: 20px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 1px -1px 1px #000;

    background: #69ace0; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #69ace0 14%, #207cca 38%, #7db9e8 66%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(14%,#69ace0), color-stop(38%,#207cca), color-stop(66%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #69ace0 14%,#207cca 38%,#7db9e8 66%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #69ace0 14%,#207cca 38%,#7db9e8 66%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #69ace0 14%,#207cca 38%,#7db9e8 66%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #69ace0 14%,#207cca 38%,#7db9e8 66%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#69ace0', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

.top {
    height: 220px;
}

.top .header {
    background-color: #09aad3;
    /*background-size: 25px 25px;*/
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #0480a7;
    height: 115px;
}

.top .header .logo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #027297;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.top {
    text-align: center;
}

.top .top-menu {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.top .top-menu .item {
    width: 190px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #363636;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
    /*font-family: Arial;*/
    font-size: 14pt;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.top .top-menu .item a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.middle .left-column .content .block .body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.middle .left-column .content .block {
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 225px;
    max-width: 225px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 7px;
    border: 3px solid #1b1b1b;
}

.middle .left-column .content .block.plain {
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 205px;
}

.middle .left-column .content .block .title {
    font-size: 16pt;
}

.middle .left-column .content .block.plain ul {
}

.middle .left-column .footer {
    margin-left: 7px;
}

ul.green-arrow-markered {
    list-style: disc outside url("list-bullet.gif");
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.left-column {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.clearer {
    clear: both;
}

.angled-stripes {
    /*
    background-color: #09aad3;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #0480a7;
    linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    */

    background-image: /* Safari 5 and earlier */
        -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 100%, 0 0,
        color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)),
        color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
        color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
        color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)),
        color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)),
        color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
        color-stop(1, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));

    background-image:   /* Chrome and Webkit Nightly build */
        -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
        );

    background-image:   /* Firefox */
        -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
        );

    background-image:   /* IE10 */
        -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
        );

    background-image:   /* opera 11+ */
        -o-linear-gradient(45deg,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
        );

    background-image:
        linear-gradient(45deg,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
        );

    background-size: 15px 15px;
    -moz-background-size: 15px 15px;
    -webkit-background-size: 15px 15px;
    -o-background-size: 15px 15px;
    -ms-background-size: 15px 15px;
}

input[type=submit], input[type=button] {
    display: none;
}

.middle {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.middle .right-column {
    color: #000;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.table-positioning {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-positioning .row-positioning {
    display: table-row;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.table-positioning .row-positioning .cell-positioning {
    display: table-cell;
}

.middle .left-column, .middle .right-column {
    display: table-cell;
}

.middle .right-column .post .title {
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: #09aad3;
}

.green-title {
    color: #4ebb30 !important;
}

.blue-title {
    color: #09aad3 !important;
}

.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.middle .right-column .post .title {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bebebe;
}

.middle .right-column .post form input, .middle .right-column .post form label, .middle .right-column .post form textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle .right-column .post form input[type=submit], .middle .right-column .post form input[type=button] {
    display: none;
}

.middle .right-column .post .image {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.middle .right-column .post .image img {
    border: none;
    min-width: 124px;
    min-height: 124px;
    width: 124px;
    height: 124px;
    max-width: 124px;
    max-height: 124px;
}

.middle .right-column .post .content {
    margin: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bebebe;
}

.middle .right-column .post {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.split-content {
    display: table;
}

.highlighted-block {
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 20px;
    min-height: 420px;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

.middle .right-column .left-post {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
}

.middle .right-column .left-post .row {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.highlighted-block img {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.highlighted-block .title {
    display: block;
    height: 110px;
}

.highlighted-block .title div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.highlighted-block .title img {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}

.middle .right-column .post .button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.middle .right-column .cell-positioning.post {
    margin: 20px;
}

.cell-positioning.wider {
    width: 65%;
}

.middle .right-column .post .input {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle .right-column .post .input * {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 50%;
}

.middle .right-column .post .input input, .middle .right-column .post .input textarea {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.middle .right-column .footer .links {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

As you can see, i have one block, `.middle`, containing the left part, `left-column` and the right part, `.right-column`.

The right column contains only one element - `.content`. But the elements of that container could be divided into several columns recursively (*it contains two columns, one of which contains two columns, one of which contain two columns...*).

So I tried to use the CSS3 `display: table;`, `display: table-row;` and `display: table-column;` properties. Somehow it helped me. A bit. I've tried to apply the same changes to my current problem but it doesn't seem to be working.  So, I decided to try *the `<div>` approach*.  The problem with this is that the `<div>`, containing the label and its input is not sizing by the maximum child' height (`<textarea>` is much larger than the `<label>`, but the container' height is as big as the label' one).

**I have two questions based on this information:**

1. Why does the *"miscalculation of the height"* happen and how do I prevent it?
2. How should I do the layout to get my code modern, stupidly simple ([KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) and yet responsive?

Comment: You do understand how the CSS box-model works, right?  http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Comment: @cimmanon the basics only. So what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why do things like that "miscalculation of the height" happen and how to prevent them?

That's because you're using `float` on all objects within the container. Floats are a little weird, so I recommend reading [this CSS-Tricks article on them](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

In short, though, when you float an element, you take it out of the document flow. When all elements in a (non-floated) container are floated, the parent thinks it doesn't have any children, and therefore collapses. There are a few ways you can fix this:

1. Set `overflow: hidden` on the parent container (this only really works if the container does not have a specified height)
2. Add `clear: both` to an element immediately after the floated elements, inside the parent container (this works well, but may add extra markup if you add elements specifically for this purpose)
3. Harness the power of the `:after` pseudo-element (this only works for browsers that support it; the good news is that the majority do, albeit possibly requiring a polyfill).

> how i should do the layout of the elements to get my code modern, stupidly simple (KISS) and yet responsive?

From what I can see here, you're doing a number of things that are making your work more difficult than is necessary. It seems to me that you're missing some fundamentals.

You might want to look more into semantic markup. You're experiencing what we in the trade call "divitis". That is, you're wrapping things in `<div>` tags that are probably better suited to other elements.

For example, every place that you use `<div class="item">`, you can change to an unordered list (`<ul>`) and each "item" is a list item (`<li>`). This saves you from attaching a class to absolutely everything.

Additionally, you don't have to reinvent the wheel with your button. There are both an `input type=button` and `<button>` element. Using either of these will open up the `form.submit` action that you can then hook into (instead of recreating it, too).

You also shouldn't need chains of CSS selectors that are half a dozen selectors long. Take a look at how [CSS and specificity works](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), or you're going to cause yourself migraines in the relatively near future.

I recommend picking up [Dan Cederholm's *Handcrafted CSS* and *Bulletproof Web Design*](http://simplebits.com/#books), as well as perusing [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/) and [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com), to get a better grasp on CSS and HTML at a fundamental level.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I adore those guys answering so deeply and clearly =) Yet, adding `overflow: hidden;` or `clear: both;` does not solve my problem =(

Comment: Tried adding `<div class="clearer"></div>` (which adds the `clear: both;`) after __`.item` elements__, __`<form>` element__, __`<textarea>` within the `.item` element__

Comment: I highly recommend reading up on how the CSS cascade and specificity work and how you can simplify both your CSS and your HTML, before you try to continue fixing this issue with what you have. As it stands, it's very likely you have things interfering with one another. Do what you can to simplify everything, then see if your problem still exists. The act of cleaning up your code might fix the problem for you.

Comment: Sorry, fixed for now =) Read a few paragraphs of the articles you recommended - yes, they are great! Fixed by simply adding floating to the `<textarea>` and replacing the `position: absolute;` with `position: relative;` =)

Answer (score 1):

Try Using

```
.input { overflow: hidden }
```

It may solve your problem.
When you have floating elements inside another one the height of this parent gets compromised since the child elements are "floating"

Comment: Thanks for the tip about _compromised height_, bug if i hide the overflowing part of my textarea - i shall not get the result desired (see the fourth screenshot).

Comment: Right, but if you are not specifying the height of that .input element that same height will be filled automatically.