# <ul> Navigation Bar Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've created a navigation bar using an `<ul>`. The issue is that the `<ul>` isn't containing the items correctly, yet it's still affects their positions. When highlighted, you can see the the `<ul>` sits above the `<li>`'s.

**Extra:**
 *The width of the `<ul>` doesn't seem to automatically set itself to the collective width of the `<li>`'s, and it's hard to notice, but the last hovered-over `<li>` keeps a faint shadow even when the `box-shadow` property is set to `none`.*

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctr4uqec/1/).

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="Index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="">About</a>

        </li>
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="">Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav {
    background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.75);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
ul.nav {
    height: 100%;
    /* Is there a way to make the width automatically size itself relative to the collective width of the menu items? */
    width: 330px;
    /* Without defining <width> the <ul> defaults to 100%. */
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0;
    /* --------------------------- The border highlights the problem. --------------------------- */
    border: 1px solid Red;
    /* The <ul> should surround the <li>'s. This is making the menu options display out-of-place. */
}
li.nav {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
a.nav {
    height: 100%;
    color: #665544;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
/* --------------- Animations --------------- */
 a.nav {
    animation: navUnfocus 0.3s ease-in forwards;
    -webkit-animation: navUnfocus 0.3s ease-in forwards;
    -moz-animation: navUnfocus 0.3s ease-in forwards;
}
a.nav:hover, a.nav:focus {
    animation: navFocus 0.3s ease-out forwards;
    -webkit-animation: navFocus 0.3s ease-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: navFocus 0.3s ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes navFocus {
    from {
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #665544;
    }
}
@keyframes navUnfocus {
    from {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #665544;
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0);
        /* --------- This is the problem where there is a small trace of a shadow --------- */
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: PLease include your code in the question, not just in a fiddle. The is doubly relevent as jsfiddle has been flakey the last couple of days.

Comment: Copy tour code into the editor, select it an click the {} button. Alos see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I Added it. You can't view the JSFiddle?

Comment: I've been having problems with jsFiddle over the last couple of days. SO recomends your question be self contained. Fiddles are great **in addition** to code in the question. I would have been able to answer your question without navigating away from SO if you'd included your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: If you're going to float anything here, float the `li` not the `a`.

Step 2: If you are floating elements be aware that they are removed from the normal document flow. Therefore the parent will collapse on it self. The most common solution is the [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/). Apply this to the `ul` e.g. `ul class="nav cf"`:  abbreviated version below:

```
.cf:before, .cf:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}


.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

[Clearfix Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ctr4uqec/9/)

Step 3: Maybe use `display:inline-block;` **instead**. Make the following changes:

```
ul.nav {
    height: 100%;
    /* Is there a way to make the width automatically size itself relative to the collective width of the menu items? */
    /*width: 330px;*/
    /* Without defining <width> the <ul> defaults to 100%. */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0;       
    border: 1px solid Red;

}

li.nav {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
a.nav {
    height: 100%;
    color: #665544;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ctr4uqec/7/)

Here's an article on the [Pros and Cons of inline-block](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow: hidden;` and removing the `height` setting from `ul.nav` [seems to fix this](http://jsfiddle.net/ctr4uqec/2/). I think that the reason for this is better explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886064/3992853).

To preserve your shadows, just removing `float: left` and `display: block` from `a.nav` as in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctr4uqec/8/) works as far as I can tell – but perhaps I'm breaking something else by doing that. Whatever the case, I'm pretty sure `display: block` on that doesn't make much sense to keep them in the row like you want.

Comment: Thank you, but now the shadows are hidden, show here: **http://jsfiddle.net/ctr4uqec/5/**

Comment: Edited my original answer with what *looks* like a fix to me in jsfiddle. My apologies if that just results in breaking something else.

Answer (score 1):

here is my own version for you, using your code with some minor modifications

http://jsfiddle.net/ctr4uqec/10/

HTML

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="Index.html">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="">About</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#page {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #0d5c27;
    text-align: center;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav {
    background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.75);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
ul.nav {
    height: 100%;
    /* Is there a way to make the width automatically size itself relative to the collective width of the menu items? */
    width: 330px;
    /* Without defining <width> the <ul> defaults to 100%. */
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0;
    /* --------------------------- The border highlights the problem. --------------------------- */
    outline: 1px solid Red;
    /* The <ul> should surround the <li>'s. This is making the menu options display out-of-place. */
}
li.nav {
    margin: 0 -2px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0px 0;
}
a.nav {
    color: #665544;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
}
/* --------------- Animations --------------- */
 a.nav {
    animation: navUnfocus 0.3s ease-in forwards;
    -webkit-animation: navUnfocus 0.3s ease-in forwards;
    -moz-animation: navUnfocus 0.3s ease-in forwards;
}
a.nav:hover, a.nav:focus {
    animation: navFocus 0.3s ease-out forwards;
    -webkit-animation: navFocus 0.3s ease-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: navFocus 0.3s ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes navFocus {
    from {
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #665544;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes navFocus {
    from {
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #665544;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes navFocus {
    from {
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #665544;
    }
}
@keyframes navUnfocus {
    from {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #665544;
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0);
        /* --------- This is the problem where there is a small trace of a shadow --------- */
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes navUnfocus {
    from {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #665544;
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0);
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes navUnfocus {
    from {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #665544;
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0);
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a thought like this(`margin: 0 -2px;`) earlier after the `inline-box` suggestion that I marked as the answer, but I never tried it. Thank you for the response! I'm using it on my WebPage :). +1.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad I was able to help! :3